# Background activity blocked while using AlarmManager. (Android Q privacy change)

Tags: android, alarmmanager, android-alarms, android-10.0

In my project I am using [AlarmManager](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/AlarmManager) in order to trigger daily [AlarmClock](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/provider/AlarmClock) but when the time comes to start an alarm following toast message occurs:

```
Background activity start from com.example.nameOfApp blocked. See g.co/dev/bgblock
```

Updated code:

-------setAlarmClock method-------

```java
private void setAlarmClock(Calendar calendar, int alarmId, String time, String timeOfTheDay, boolean action) {
        AlarmManager manager = (AlarmManager) getActivity().getSystemService(Context.ALARM_SERVICE);
        Intent intent = new Intent(getActivity(), AlarmClockReceiver.class);
        PendingIntent pendingIntent = PendingIntent.getBroadcast(getActivity(), alarmId, intent, 0);

        if (action) {
            manager.setRepeating(AlarmManager.RTC_WAKEUP, calendar.getTimeInMillis(),
                    AlarmManager.INTERVAL_DAY, pendingIntent);
            if (Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= Build.VERSION_CODES.M) {
                manager.setExactAndAllowWhileIdle(AlarmManager.RTC_WAKEUP, calendar.getTimeInMillis(), pendingIntent);
            }
        } else {
            manager.cancel(pendingIntent);
        }
    }
```

-------AlarmClockReceiver class-------

```
public class AlarmClockReceiver extends BroadcastReceiver {
    @Override
    public void onReceive(Context context, Intent intent) {
        String alarmAction = AlarmClock.ACTION_SET_ALARM;
        Intent i = new Intent(alarmAction);
        i.putExtra(AlarmClock.EXTRA_SKIP_UI, true);
        i.putExtra(AlarmClock.EXTRA_MESSAGE, "Time for taking medicine!");
        i.addFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_NEW_TASK);
        context.startActivity(i);
    }
}
```

Moreover in AndroidManifest I included following line:

```
<uses-permission android:name="com.android.alarm.permission.SET_ALARM"/>
```

I am aware that it's connected with new Android Q privacy change. From the aforementioned [link](http://g.co/dev/bgblock) it's said:

> Apps running on Android Q can start activities only when one or more of the following conditions are met:
>
> ...
>
> The app receives a notification **PendingIntent** from the system. In the case of pending intents for services and broadcast receivers, the app can start activities for a few seconds after the pending intent is sent.

If I understood it correctly this is exactly my case. Nevertheless aforementioned toast message occurs.

Comment: Yours isn't a "notification `PendingIntent`". It's an alarm `PendingIntent`.

Answer (score 2):

The PendingIntent is valid (in order to start an activity) only if you set the intent in a notification using the method `setContentIntent`. So what you can do is to post a notification instead of starting directly an activity. When the user tap on the notification the pending intent will be used to start the activity.
**Edit**: as alternative you need to ask the [SYSTEM_ALERT_WINDOW](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/Manifest.permission#SYSTEM_ALERT_WINDOW) permission but you won't be able to execute the app on Android Go because it's not possible to use this permission on that version.

Comment: Not sure if you read documentation this is what  PendingIntent.getActivity() does `Retrieve a PendingIntent that will start a new activity, like calling Context#startActivity(Intent)`so this is exactly the same thing what you said without creating my own receiver.

Comment: yes, I know, but with Android Q there's the only thing you can do to call startActivity

Comment: Can you have a look over my updated code, I got stuck why this error appears while triggering `onReceive` metod.

Comment: you need to create the intent as you did in your previous code, don't use the parameter of receiver

Comment: So what do you mean by `than call startActivity from your receiver` in original answer, I thought that I should build my own receiver

Comment: you need to create your own intent object in the receiver, nothing more.

Comment: Sorry maybe I misunderstood  you once more but when I create my intent which triggers `AlarmClock` inside `AlarmClockReceiver` the same toast message occurs as it was at the beginning. If you can kindly take a look at my code once more and point out my mistake.

Comment: it seems correct, I would say a platform bug in this case.

Comment: @PawełBęza Updated the reply after more testing.

Comment: I mean it's maybe some solution but in my case when I'm using `AlarmClock` and interaction with user shouldn't be necessary to trigger an alarm. It would be the same as I would need to tap notification from wake up alarm to allow him ringing.

Comment: updated the answer with alternative, I think it's all what you can do :/

Comment: I have same problem @PawełBęza did u solve it? Its comical my app is alarm app, alarms are its core functionality, and I am not allowed to run alarm. Crazy